# Clearing all the items not updating the view

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am working on a web application where I have a delete all call to a web api which works fine but the view is not updating until I refresh the page

ViewModel

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new UsersViewModel());
    });


function UsersViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    var baseUri = "http://localhost:59161/api/customers";
    self.users = ko.observableArray(); 

    self.create = function (formElement) {
        $.post(baseUri, $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function (o) {
                self.users.push(o);
            });
    }
    self.update = function (user) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: baseUri,
            data: user
        });
    }
    self.remove = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: baseUri 
        }).done(function () {
            self.users.remove();
        });
    }

    $.getJSON(baseUri, self.users);
}
```

HTML

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove All" data-bind="click: $root.remove" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.FirstName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.LastName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.Address"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

**am I missing anything?**

Comment: My Bad, I wasn't removing all from the observable array

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, I wasn't removing all from the observable array

```
self.remove = function () {               
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "/api/users"
                }).done(function () {
                    self.users.removeAll();
                });
            }
```